# how to convert string to char in c++

Tags: c++, string, char

I have a function

```
void match(char expectedToken);
```

that takes char however  I have a a string s and I want to pass it to the function

I tried this way of conversion

```
char* p = new char[s.length()+1];
  memcpy(p, s.c_str(), s.length()+1);
match(p);
```

but it didn't work and gave an error any help please??

Comment: Please read a C++ tutorial. The mere use of `new char[]` here is non-idiomatic code that no C++ tutorial would ever teach you. The remaining issues are just follow-ups caused by this flawed approach. Also, please read the Stack Overflow guidelines, your question is really bad.

Comment: `p` is a pointer to `char`, so you meant `match(*p);` maybe?

Comment: no it will give only the first char

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of bothering with c-style character strings.

Comment: @BasantAmer *"no it will give only the first char"* -- Well which char do you want, if not the first?

Comment: I think that you wanted to convert a string to an array of char (char []) instead of only a char, so your function could be "void match(char* expectedToken);".

Comment: I want all of them @ Benjamin Lindley

Comment: @BasantAmer Well a char is ***one*** character. So you can only pass one character to this function.

Comment: The function takes one character. You can't give it more than one. What is it that you're really trying to do?

Comment: You can call the function multiple times, each time passing a different character from the string. Is that what you want?

Answer (score -1):

String is itself an array and you can loop through it and if you like you can copy the contents of string array into char. Don't forget to include the string file which is `#include<string>`

```
 string s = "text"; 
 int n = s.length() + 1;
 char c[n];
 for(int i=0; i<s.length(); ++i){
   c[i] = s[i];
 }
```

And now you can output the values stored in char.

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok,thus I will have array of char how can i pass it to my func as a char?

Comment: create a function func( string array, length) and inside the function you can loop as mentioned above and then you have the values stored in char.